# How does this notch filter work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, low-pass, high-pass-filter, band-pass

I am trying to learn filters.

In the following circuit, the author says that negative and positive feedback are used. I couldn't understand what the circuit parts do.

Actually I got the negative feedback highpass parts but the low pass part is a little different from normal filters because C2 doesn't bind with ground.

[image]

Comment: Find the transfer function, put in some component values and look at it than conclude ;).

Comment: Thank you my friend but for now i need to understand how it works. And actually i got negative feedback highpass parts but the low pass part is little different from normal filters. cause C2 doesnt bind with ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any calculation:

- The combination C2-R4 forms a highpass in the feedback loop (and, thus, acts as a **lowpass** for the input signal)
- The combination C1-R3 forms a simple **highpass** in the forward path.
- Both functions - related to the NON-INVERTING input - make together a (positive) **bandpass** response.
- At the same time, the input signal is connected also to the inverting terminal. Hence, at the output we have the DIFFERENCE between the (positive) bandpass signal and the constant (negative) amplified version of the input signal (the corresponding gain: -R2/R1).
- If the negative gain has a value which can compensate the bandpass maximum value (at cener frequency), the **output** is **zero** at this single frequency.

Comment: Thank you sir .I don't know highpass in the feedback. Where can i learn these kind of informations. Can you suggest any book or source?

Comment: The capacitive iimpedance of C2 will decrease for rising frequencies....and the output voltage (node between C2 and R4) will increase. That is a typical highpass function. And the same applies to C1-R3. Perhaps it is easier for you to see it from the input: In this case, R4-C2 forms a lowpass of first-order.